# Where to host depositions?

Tags: deposition

I'm part of a new law firm and trying to get insight about how other law firms host their video and audio files from depositions, whether it be cloud servers, internal networks, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We store video and audio files on a server, which used to be local and recently was converted to a cloud based server.

We generally do not "host" audio and video files from depositions in the sense of making them available to third-parties or the public. If we need to share a video or audio file with another party or the court, we generally do so via a flash drive that is hand delivered.

But, there are some instances where we have made disclosures to third parties in the case by providing the third-parties with access to a Drop Box folder. Online delivery of video and audio is not acceptable in any of our local state courts, although it may be acceptable in our local federal courts where all evidence must be uploaded and presented electronically.

Very short clips are sometimes shared with third-parties via email attachments.

Answer (score 0):

We put them in the cloud with all the rest of our files.